# TypeScript: ¿Que tipo de dato es este? ¿Como uso la librería D3 sin mandársela como parametro?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tipos

¿que tipo de dato es un elemento html para typeScript?

```
let legend = new Legend;
legend.container(this.container.nativeElement)
```

this.container es un elemento 'div' de html.

¿Es correcto mandar la libria D3 como parametro como esta actualmente? ¿como seria lo adecuado?
Actualmente esta en JS legend pero hay que pasarlo a TS. Planeo crear una interface "Legend".
Actualmente se le manda los parametros asi:

```
legend.container(this.container.nativeElement)
      .type(type)
      .data(values)
      .dataChart(dataChart)
      .config(this.data.legendConfig)
      .dataMap(this.data.rowFieldMap)
      .maskTitle(this.chartService.parseName)
      .range(this.data.range)
      .d3(d3);

    legend.draw();
```

d3 es una libreria de js.
La funcion de legend es un panel opcional que si se activa muestra ciertos nombres.
Adjunto capturas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: sería útil saber qué librería estás usando

Comment: Typescript tiene el tipo nativo `HTMLDivElement`. Puedes obtener un elemento del DOM con la sentencia `let container: HTMLDivElement = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>("#myContainerId")!`

Comment: No estaría entendiendo. Las librerias del tsConfig son estas 
"es2018",
          "es2015",
          "es2020",
          "dom"
@JaimeMenéndez la interface para container quedo asi: 
container: HTMLDivElement;
¿Esta ok?

Comment: Si. Si el container es un div justo como lo pones está bien. De cualquier forma la última palabra siempre la tiene typescript. ¿Te lo acepta?

Comment: Funciono perfecto. Me faltaría el tipo para la libreria/modulo D3.
Lei algo de que se usaba npm install @type d3 pero no me funciono. 
En la aplicacion d3 esta instalado en otra carpeta y se le pasa por parametro. Especificamente hay 3 partes, las que trabajo son frontEnd y Charts. En frontEnd esta instalado d3 y se le pasa por parametro a charts. En este caso a Legend que usa d3.